# Comment dire « tout le monde sait faire quelque chose » avec une double négation ?

Tags: négation, double-négation

La phrase que je voulais utiliser était « personne ne sait rien faire », mais elle a la signification inverse. Comment dire « personne ne se trouve dans la situation de pouvoir dire “je ne sais rien faire” » ?

La phrase « Tout le monde sait faire quelque chose » convient parfaitement, mais j'aurais voulu utiliser une double négation et le mot « personne ». Comment exprimer cette idée ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On peut rajouter un verbe qui n'apporte pas de sens mais qui permet de séparer les deux négations.

> Il n'y a personne qui ne sache rien faire.

On peut aussi faire porter l'une des négations sur un mot qui n'est pas le verbe.

> Personne n'est incapable de faire quoi que ce soit.

Je préfère quand même la formulation positive à ces doubles négations.

Comment: La seconde phrase se réduit à « Tout le monde sait tout faire. »

Comment: @LPH Non, elle veut dire “tout le monde sait faire quelque chose”.

Comment: Il me semble que « quoi que ce soit » signifie « tout » ; par exemple, « Quoi que ce soit  qu'il vous faille, c'est sur la table. » veut bien dire « Tout ce qu'il peut vous falloir est sur la table. » ; encore un exemple bien que ça n'ajoute peut être rien de plus : « Quoi que ce soit qu'il ait appris, il ne s'en rappelle pas. » ; je ne vois pas comment considérer qu'il s'agisse seulement de quelque chose, c'est de tout qu'il s'agit (« II a tout oublié. » et non « Il a oublié quelque chose. »).

Comment: @LPH Non : dans « Personne n'est incapable de faire quoi que ce soit », le « quel que ce soit » est sous la négation. C'est la négation de « il existe quelqu'un tel que pour toute chose, il incapable de faire cette chose ». Le sens est donc le même que « pour toute personne, il existe quelque chose que cette personne n'est pas incapable de faire » (la négation échange les quantificateurs existentiels et universels, si ça te parle).

Comment: Voir aussi au TLFi à [quoi (que ce soit)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quoi), en contexte forclusif, synon. _quelque chose_ et au LBU§737, qui que ce soit, quoi que ce soit « une personne, une chose quelconques ». [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quoi_que_ce_soit) semble errer avec un propos bizarre et [Larousse](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/quoi_que/65797/locution?q=quoi+que+ce+soit#16001919) est peu utile quand il dit _quelque chose que ce soit_ ; ça pourrait faire l'objet d'une question, la négation semble être un sujet populaire...

Comment: Le raisonnement est juste après la première affirmation : la négation de « Ex tel que (Ac  P(x,c)) » (appelé K) est bien équivalent à « Ax (Ec tel que  non P(x,c)) » (appelé L) (E= il existe, A= pour tous, c= une chose à faire, P(y,c)=y ne peut faire c *ou* y est incapable de faire c) ; mais ce qui est sous la négation c'est seulement « être incapable », c'est à dire P;  on peut mettre le complément en évidence en le plaçant en tête de phrase pour essayer de mieux voir : « Quoi que ce soit, personne n'est incapable de le faire. ». (champ 1)

Comment: S'il y a deux choses seulement, quoi que ce soit des deux tout le monde sait la faire, donc tout le monde sait faire deux, donc tout le monde sait tout faire ; c'est le même problème quel que soit le nombre des choses, deux ou mille et autant que l'on veuille. « Ec » n'est pas « quoi que ce soit », c'est « une chose » ; c'est « Ac » qui est « quoi que ce soit », mais on le trouve dans (K), dont il faut prendre la négation pour arriver à L, qui est la phrase discutée. (fin)

Answer (score 4):

Je propose:

> Aucune personne ne sait rien faire

*Aucune* permet de souligner la première négation et souligne l'inverse de *tout le monde*.

**Modification**

Je propose pour répondre au commentaire de @RomainValeri cette nouvelle version:

> Il n'y a aucune personne qui ne sache rien faire

Ou, plus concis:

> Il n'est personne qui ne sache rien faire

Comment: Il me semble qu'il reste un flottement de sens. Le risque d'incompréhension est atténué mais toujours présent.

Comment: (Il n'est personne qui ne sait rien faire.) Si la proposition principale est négative, interrogative ou hypothétique, la proposition relative est normalement au subjonctif. (BDL)

Comment: @LPH édité et corrigé merci

Answer (score 3):

Je propose d'ajouter juste un *ne*:

> Personne ne sait ne rien faire.

Comment: C'était trop simple pour qu'on y pense…

Comment: Il me semble que « rien faire » prenne une autre dimension ici, rien que du fait de l'addition de « ne » ; « faire qqc » ne signifie plus « avoir l'expérience que demande une certaine activité et s'en servir » (faire de la sérigraphie, par exemple) mais seulement « s'occuper »; en d'autres mots ce que l'on dit ça serait plutôt « Personne ne sait comment rien faire. », « Personne ne sait comment rester inoccupé. »

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a personne ne sachant rien faire.

(ce qui est différent de « Il n'y a personne sachant ne rien faire. », qui n'a rien à voir avec la question)

Answer (score -1):

*Personne ne sait rien faire* signifie que *tout le monde sait faire quelque chose*.
*Personne* étant déjà la négation de *tout le monde*. Il n'y a qu'une négation à rajouter ensuite pour arriver au résultat. Donc ta phrase était bonne mais je rajouterais le mot *rien* pour appuyer la négation.

- Tout le monde ne sait rien faire = personne sait faire quoique ce soit.
- Tout le monde sait faire quelque chose = personne ne sait pas rien faire.

Après il ne faut pas abuser des négations à rallonge, en général moins il y en a plus la phrase est claire et n'induit pas en erreur (dès qu'il y a plus d'une négation il faut réfléchir).

Donc la meilleur formule, et de loin la plus utilisée reste : *Tout le monde sait faire quelque chose*

Comment: *Personne ne sait rien faire*, c'est une seule négation avec deux pronoms indéfinis.

Comment: Personne est le sujet (et le contraire de tout le monde), donc ça ajoute une négation. La seconde négation est apportée par *ne [...] rien*.

Comment: Je trouve que « personne ne sait rien faire » sonne mal et je ne l'utiliserais pas, mais ça veut bien dire que chaque individu a un ensemble de capacités vide. C'est comme « je n'ai jamais vu personne », qui est pour le coup bien idiomatique et qui ne signifie pas « à tout moment, je voyais quelqu'un ».